# functions with data.table variables which names are stored in a character vector

Tags: r, data.table

I am not a big data.table expert but I am somehow puzzled by some things. Here is my simple example:

```
test<-data.table(x= 1:10,y= 1:10,z= 1:10, l = 11:20,d= 21:30)
test<-test[,..I:=.I]
vec_of_names = c("z","l","d")

function_test<-function(x,y){
  sum(x)+y
}

vec_of_final_names<-c("sum_z","sum_l","sum_d")
```

When I then attempt do to something like this:

```
for (i in 1:length(vec_of_names)){
  test<-test[,vec_of_final_names[i]:=function_test(x=.SD,y=eval(parse(text=vec_of_names[i]))),.SDcols=c("x","y"),by=..I]
}
```

I get an error:

```
 Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'z' not found
```

Whereas code below works perfectly fine but is a little bit ugly and also slow. Maybe somebody can suggest better alternatives.

```
for (i in 1:length(vec_of_names)){
  test<-test[,vec_of_final_names[i]:=function_test(x=eval(parse(text=paste("c(",paste(c("x","y"),collapse=","),")",sep=""))),y=eval(parse(text=vec_of_names[i]))),by=..I]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, corrected in the main post

Comment: In my opinion, it is your function, or perhaps your data structure, that is the problem here. Don't `sum(DT)` where DT is a data.frame, data.table or list of vectors. Doing a by-row operation is another red flag that the approach is probably misguided. It seems that you should be doing... `m = as.matrix(test[, 1:5, with=FALSE]); m %*% rbind(1, 1, diag(3))` or similar.

Comment: This was just an example. The idea was more - suppose that you have a huge amount of variables stored in some vector - which will be x in your function. Then you want to iterate over y, which is stored in another vector how to do that in a clean manner

Comment: If `x` is a vector it's fine, but in your example you are setting `x=.SD`. Even if you adjust this to `unlist(.SD)` as in akrun's answer, it will still be very inefficient, especially alongside `by=..I`.

Comment: Sure but what do you propose then ? Like writing it like this: function_test(x=c(x1,x2,x3,....x100000),y=some_stuff[i]). Can you explain how to pass x without writing it explicitly and without using .SD

Comment: Why I am down voted consistently for this post.

Comment: It looks to me like your data structure should be something else, possibly a matrix (which works well for the example, anyways). You are not downvoted "consistently", just twice. I made the second one because I don't think the question is likely to be useful to others; it's not some sort of personal attack or something, just my opinion on the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After specifying the `.SDcols` and grouped by = `..I` (the `..I` is a strange name for a column name), we `unlist` the `.SD`, get the `sum`, get the values of 'vec_of_names' in a `list` with `mget`, do the `+` of corresponding elements of this with the `sum(unlist(.SD))` and assign (`:=`) it to 'vec_of_final_names' to create new columns

```
test[, (vec_of_final_names) := Map(`+`, sum(unlist(.SD)), 
                    mget(vec_of_names)), by = ..I, .SDcols = x:y]
```

Based on the example, this can also be done without the grouping variable

```
test[, (vec_of_final_names) := Map(`+`, list(x+y), mget(vec_of_names))]
```

Or by specifying the `.SDcols`

```
test[, (vec_of_final_names) := Map(`+`, list(Reduce(`+`, .SD)), 
                            mget(vec_of_names)), .SDcols = x:y]
```

---

Or using the OP's function

```
test[, (vec_of_final_names) := Map(function_test, list(unlist(.SD)), 
                mget(vec_of_names)), ..I, .SDcols = x:y]
test
#      x  y  z  l  d ..I sum_z sum_l sum_d
# 1:  1  1  1 11 21   1     3    13    23
# 2:  2  2  2 12 22   2     6    16    26
# 3:  3  3  3 13 23   3     9    19    29
# 4:  4  4  4 14 24   4    12    22    32
# 5:  5  5  5 15 25   5    15    25    35
# 6:  6  6  6 16 26   6    18    28    38
# 7:  7  7  7 17 27   7    21    31    41
# 8:  8  8  8 18 28   8    24    34    44
# 9:  9  9  9 19 29   9    27    37    47
#10: 10 10 10 20 30  10    30    40    50
```

Comment: would that would on any function, basically my point is that I would like to specify many variables in .SD and then iterate over all the variables in y; It would be something like function_test(x=.SD,y=vec[i])

Comment: @VitalijsJascisens  I used your function please check the update

Comment: Thanks, it seems that it is working but a little bit unclear why it is still so slow

Comment: @VitalijsJascisens  It is slow because we are doing the `unlist` by each row

Comment: But do you have any ideas how to speed this up ? But again function should be arbitrary!

Comment: @VitalijsJascisens  I updated with two more options.